# Wrong format of TAG command imacros

Tags: imacros

I want to launch a robot who will post in others twitter 
and when i try it in imacros software i got this:

```
Error -1100: Wrong format of TAG 
POST=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:NewTweetButton<SP>usizeFull<SP>jstooltip<SP>btn<SP>primary-btn<SP>tweet-action<SP>tweet-btn command, at line: 19
```

heres the code :

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://livaweightloss.com/1.php
WAIT SECONDS=4.6523133356232
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2



URL GOTO=https://twitter.com/syedalirazi
WAIT SECONDS=5.79524212
TAG POST=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:NewTweetButton<SP>usizeFull<SP>jstooltip<SP>btn<SP>primary-btn<SP>tweet-action<SP>tweet-btn
TAG POST=1 TYPE=DIV FORM=ACTION://upload.twitter.com/i/tweet/create_with_media.iframe ATTR=NAME:tweet
SIZE X=1150 Y=713
WAIT SECONDS=5.08521232
WAIT SECONDS=5.0456454
DS CMD=CLICK X=475 Y=257 CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}
WAIT SECONDS=3.5421355412
TAG POST=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION://upload.twitter.com/i/tweet/creat_with_media.iframe ATTR=TXT:Tweet<SP>Reply<SP>Send<SP>Message
WAIT SECONDS=3.5421355412
```

Comment: Here is a right format of `TAG` command: **`TAG POS=...`**

Answer (score 0):

The correct format of the command is

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:NewTweetButton<SP>usizeFull<SP>jstooltip<SP>btn<SP>primary-btn<SP>tweet-action<SP>tweet-btn
```

POS means position, `POS=1` means Macro selects the first matching element.